Is there a word for problems that arise from solving another problem?
For example plastics were invented to make life easier. However, the invention of plastics created a new problem for us; plastic pollution.

side effects, repercussions, consequences,... Often encapsulated in the "innocent"  question "What could possibly go wrong?" (Answer; A lot!, Everything!).

Unintended consequences is commonly used to describe the unexpected side effects of a policy change, which usually has other intended results. Wikipedia describes this as:

outcomes of a purposeful action that are not intended or foreseen.

If the unintended consequence is a new problem, it's more specifically an unexpected drawback:

An unexpected detriment occurring in addition to the desired effect of the policy (e.g., while irrigation schemes provide people with water for agriculture, they can increase waterborne diseases that have devastating health effects, such as schistosomiasis).

This would include your plastic pollution example.

The Wikipedia example also has several alternative names for the phenomenon, such as the more colloquial knock-on effects. But certainly unintended consequences is a widely used phrase.
